# Data Validation, Input Message, Application Defined Error for .InputTitle line in property definitions

Tags: excel, syntax-error, range, validation, vba

I am trying to insert a Data Validation Input Message into cells as my program progresses through a row of cells.  The message is a string collected from controls in my code (not included below).

I cannot enter my .InputTitle value.  When I comment this line out, it works fine.

Here, I have my loop:

```
Dim phaserangecell As Range 

Set phaserange = Sheet1.Range(Cells(rowofpersonnel, startingpoint), Cells(rowofpersonnel, startingpoint + phaselength - 1)) 'This is the range through which I am moving.

For Each phaserangecell In phaserange.Cells 

commentmessage = commentmessage & checkboxcollection(collectionindex).box.Caption & ": " & hourspermonth & " hrs/month + " & extra & " custom hours." & Chr(13)

With phaserangecell.Validation 
  .Delete
  .InputTitle = "Personnel assumptions for this month:" 'Error thrown here
  .InputMessage = commentmessage & Chr(13) & "Total Hours: " & hourspermonth + extra 
End With

Next phaserangecell
```

Why is this incorrect?  The .InputMessage works fine, but the .InputTitle throws an error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem, and just figured it out. It's because the Title is too long. Who knows why the heck the error couldn't have been "InputTitle is limited to 32 characters" but that's what the problem is.